# Apache Commons CLI : Getting list of values for an option

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons

For a CLI, I have a requirement to pass in an array of ints as input for a particular option.

Example - The below command would take in an array of customerIds and perform some operations.

> myCommand -c 123 124 125

I have implemented the CLI using Apache commons CLI, and I am using getOptionValues("c") to retrieve this array.

The problem is that, this is returning only the first element in the array, i.e. [123], while I am expecting it to return [123, 124, 125].

A condensed version of my code,

```
CommandLine cmd;
CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
if (cmd.hasOption("c")){
String[] customerIdArray = cmd.getOptionValues("c");
// Code to parse data into int
}
```

Can someone help me identify the issue here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to set maximum the number of argument values the option can take, otherwise it assumes the option only has 1 argument value

```
Options options = new Options();
Option option = new Option("c", "c desc");
// Set option c to take maximum of 10 arguments
option.setArgs(10);
options.addOption(option);
```

Comment: And if the maximum number of argument values is unknown? Is it possible to have a syntax with  bracket?

Answer (score 55):

I'd like to add this here as an answer to @Zangdak and to add my findings on the same problem.

If you do not call `#setArgs(int)` then a RuntimeException will occur. When you know the exact maximum amount of arguments to this option, then set this specific value. When this value is not known, the class Option has a constant for it: `Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES`

This would change gerrytans answer to the following:

```
Options options = new Options();
Option option = new Option("c", "c desc");
// Set option c to take 1 to oo arguments
option.setArgs(Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES);
options.addOption(option);
```

Comment: Yes, that what I did but I wanted to get a syntax more like the following : `cmd -opt1 { V1 V2 ... Vn } arg ` but it seems that doen't exist so I just place the arguments before options with unlimited values.

Comment: @Zangdok If I understand you correctly, which took me to the same question, it is no problem for UNLIMITED_VALUES to have another option after all that values.
I can confirm, that something like `cmd --opt={V1 V2 ... Vn } -o --debug` is working

Comment: No, another option after an options with unlimited values works well. I wanted to have an argument after such option. Anyway, I will try your syntax.

Comment: You can also use OptionBuilder.hasArgs()

Answer (score 16):

It looks like i am a bit late for the party but apache commons cli evolved and now (at least in 1.3.1) we have a new way to set that there can be unlimited number of arguments

```
Option c = Option.builder("c")
        .hasArgs() // sets that number of arguments is unlimited
        .build();
        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption(c);
```

Comment: If you're calling hasArgs() then hasArg() call is redundand

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify two parameters `setArgs` and `setValueSeparator`. Then you can pass a list of arguments like `-k=key1,key2,key3`.

```
Option option = new Option("k", "keys", true, "Description");
// Maximum of 10 arguments that can pass into option
option.setArgs(10);
// Comma as separator
option.setValueSeparator(',');
```