# Apache CLI Argument and Options set up?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I'm having an issue properly setting up some options in Apache CLI.

I'm trying for something like this...

```
usage: ViewReport -r <file> -d <name> [-rp [arg1] [arg2] [arg3] ... ] [OPTIONS]
 -r <file>                Report path
 -d <name>                DB Config Name
 -rp <name|class|value>   list of report parameters
OPTIONS
-preview
....
```

I need the -rp option to have unlimited amount of args and each arg would be a comma delimited list of name,className,objectValue.

I can't figure how to configure my options to handle something similar to this for CLI to handle a list as input.

***EDIT***
Lets say Args need to be a list item pair name=value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to unlimited option arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24676270/2764459)

This is possible using

```
Option.setArgs(Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES)
```

Where the parameters to the options must be space separated. The rest (e.g. splitting up the args) is up to you